# ValueError: Cannot assign User: issue on my OneToOneField relationship

Tags: python, django

I'm facing a really odd problem with OneToOneField. I've a really simple model like

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

The problem is with my method [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) in the migration. I've written a 0002_addusers migration that depends on 0001_initial and the code is the following:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    def create_users(apps, schema_editor):
        u = User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@aaa.com', 'admin')
        u.save()

        du = User.objects.create_user(username='doc01', password='doc01')
        du.save()

def create_doctors(apps, schema_editor):
    Doctor = apps.get_model('custom_user', 'Doctor')
    du = User.objects.get(username='doc01')

    d = Doctor(user=du)
    d.save()

dependencies = [
    ('custom_user', '0001_initial')
]

operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(create_users),
    migrations.RunPython(create_doctors),
]
```

What is really weird for me is that this really simple code works in views, works in shell, works everywhere except in the migration :)

The traceback is the follow:

```
line 23, in create_doctors
d = Doctor(user=du)
...
ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: doc01>": "Doctor.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

Thank you a lot for any support!

**EDIT:**
I found out the solution. I just had to call the RunPython

migrations.RunPython(create_users, create_doctor)

as [Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2089937/avinash-kr-mallik) suggested even without moving the functions outside the class.

It seems that subsequent functions have to be called as arguments of a single RunPython call.

Answer (score 4):

The suggested answer to run `migrations.RunPython(create_users, create_doctor)` doesn't solve your issue, it just makes it invisible.

The second argument of [RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython) is the function that will be called during a rollback, this is why it did not raise any exception when migrating upwards. You never called the function `create_doctors`.

Your issue is caused by `du` not being a `User` instance. This can be caused in migrations when not using `apps.get_model` to get the model class. You should use the following code instead:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    def create_users(apps, schema_editor):
        User = apps.get_model('auth', 'User')  # Here you get the user programatically, it is a good practise in migrations
        u = User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@aaa.com', 'admin')
        u.save()

        du = User.objects.create_user(username='doc01', password='doc01')
        du.save()

    def create_doctors(apps, schema_editor):
        Doctor = apps.get_model('custom_user', 'Doctor')
        User = apps.get_model('auth', 'User')  # Here you get the user programatically, it is a good practise in migrations
        du = User.objects.get(username='doc01')

        d = Doctor(user=du)
        d.save()

    dependencies = [
        ('custom_user', '0001_initial')
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_users),
        migrations.RunPython(create_doctors),
    ]
```

Comment: thank you so much! User = apps.get_model('auth', 'User') solved my error. For every model you want to reference, you must use apps.get_model!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in your migration code. Define your methods outside the Migration class then call it from migration's RunPython command.

Try below code in your migration file. This will work.

```
def create_users(apps, schema_editor):
    u = User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@aaa.com', 'admin')
    u.save()

    du = User.objects.create_user(username='doc01', password='doc01')
    du.save()

def create_doctors(apps, schema_editor):
    Doctor = apps.get_model('custom_user', 'Doctor')
    du = User.objects.get(username='doc01')
    # We can't import the Doctor model directly, But we can create it. Try this - 
    Doctor.objects.create(user=du)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('custom_user', '0001_initial')
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_users, create_doctors),
    ]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply but it doesn't work. The error is the same I got in my post.

ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: doc01>": "Doctor.user" must be a "User" instance.

Comment: Just updated my answer. Try it. This should be the solution. We can not import the model directly in migration. 

Try it and let me know

Comment: I've updated the first post. Thanks Avinash, the problem was my own calls to RunPython. Now with the new RunPython it works also if the functions are in the migration class.

Answer (score 0):

Importing models in a "migration" file will not work if done the "traditional" way. Check this https://www.spheron1.uk/2016/05/15/valueerror-in-django-migration/ to import `User` model and the documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations for an example.